# Relation between Potential energy and torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy, torque

I know, this may seem as a bit of a weird question. As we know that the relation between force and potential energy i.e: $$F = -\frac{\text{d}U}{\text{d}x}$$
so can we say that relation between torque about an axis and potential energy to be: $$\tau = -\frac{\text{d}U}{\text{d}\theta}$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is yes, as long as your system is conservative.

Longer answer is that the Euler-Lagrange equations tell you what the equations of motion really are for these systems, so you setup the Lagrangian $L(r, \theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta}) = T(\dot{r},\dot{\theta}) - U(r,\theta)$, where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is potential energy. Then calculate:

${d \over dt} {\partial L \over \partial \dot{\theta}}={\partial L \over \partial \theta}$.

In most cases, ${\partial L \over \partial \theta}$ is exactly $-dU\over d\theta$,and the left hand side turns out to be $I\alpha$.

Comment: But what happens if the force is non conservative?

Comment: "Short answer is yes" yes to what? Did he ask any question? I can't find one.

Comment: "so can we say that relation between torque about an axis and potential energy to be ....?"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best definition of torque is the work per unit angle which can be done by a force which is acting in a manner that tends to cause a rotation. If motion occurs then τ = +dU/dθ where U is the total energy of the rotating system (not just the potential energy).  Your expression refers to the torque coming from an external source, such as a deformed spring which is losing potential energy as it causes a rotation.